# How to get generic's class

Tags: java, generics, syntax

```
Class Model<T>{

   private T t;

   .....


   private void someMethod(){
       //now t is null
       Class c = t.getClass();
   } 

   .....

}
```

Of course it throws NPE.

```
Class c = t.getClass();
```

What syntax should i use to get class of T if my instance is null?
Is it possible?

Comment: If your instance is null, how would t have a class type?

Comment: It's not possible, to the best of my knowledge. Remember, Generics are compile-time, not runtime. A more common way to deal with this would be to store a Class object that keeps the class (if you really need it).

Comment: A agree with, Kylar and froadie: you need to add an extra check for non-null value for "t".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible due to type erasure.

There is the following workaround:

```
class Model<T> { 

    private T t; 
    private Class<T> tag;

    public Model(Class<T> tag) {
       this.tag = tag;
    }

    private void someMethod(){ 
       // use tag
    }  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with reflection:

```
Field f = this.getClass().getField("t");
Class tc = f.getType();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without passing in the class:

```
class Model<T> {
  Class<T> c = (Class<T>) DAOUtil.getTypeArguments(Model.class, this.getClass()).get(0);
}
```

You need two functions from this file: http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/source/browse/trunk/dao/src/main/java/com/googlecode/genericdao/dao/DAOUtil.java

For more explanation: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860