# How can i get class of Generic parameter

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get type of a generic parameter in java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)
>   [How to get generic’s class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223233/how-to-get-generics-class)

How can i get class of Generic parameter.

```
 public <T extends BeanProxiable> void method(){
    Class claz = T.class
 }
```

It's wrong. Why? How to solve this problem?

Comment: you can find the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223233/how-to-get-generics-class

Comment: your method that returns an object that extends class `BeanProxiable` then why do u need that class reference here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the type dynamically, however the compiler doesn't do this for you automagically.

```
public abstract class LastActionHero<H extends Hero>(){
    protected final Class<H> hClass;
    protected LastActionHero(Class<H> hClass) {
        this.hClass = hClass;
    }
    // use hClass how you like.
}
```

BTW: It not impossible to get this dynamically, but it depends on how it is used. e.g

```
public class Arnie extends LastActionHero<MuscleHero> { }
```

It is possible to determine that Arnie.class has a super class with a Generic parameter of MuscleHero.

```
public class Arnie<H extend Hero> extends LastActionHero<H> { }
```

The generic parameter of the super class will be just H in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

T's type is only known at compile time.

Once the program starts to run, T's type will be Object.

This is how generics work in Java.